# List only first-level children of specific custom taxonomy term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a site set up with the following:

- **Post Type:** product
- **Taxonomy:** product_cat
- **Taxonomy Slug:** hydro

The term hydro has several immediate child terms and several grandchild terms.

I need to write a loop that will display only the first-level children of the custom taxonomy term "hydro" (i.e - skip grandchild terms), along with a permalink to their respective taxonomy archive pages.

I've tried working with `get_terms()` in various incarnations but I just can't get it right.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need the term id of hydro term, you can retrive it using [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

```
$hydro = get_term_by('slug', 'hydro', 'product_cat');
```

After that, you can use the term id as `'parent'` argument for `get_terms`

```
$hydro_children = get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'parent' => $hydro->term_id ) );
```

Now you can display a list of this children:

```
if ( ! empty($hydro_children) ) {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach( $hydro_children as $hydro_child ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($hydro_child, 'product_cat') . '">';
    echo $hydro_child->name . '</a></li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

And/or run a post query for posts with `$hydro_children` terms attached, and if you want you can skip posts having only children of `$hydro_children` terms (grand children of 'hydro') thanks to `'include_children'` argument of tax query:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product', // I guess
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => wp_list_pluck($hydro_children, 'term_id'),
      'include_children' => false
    )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I follow your logic and it looks good. However the `foreach` loop seems to be breaking my page. When I comment it out it displays properly, but of course it also hides the actual list that I need to display.

Comment: @Evster Sure, I forgot first argument for `get_terms`. Now I've fixed it.

Comment: Yep that was the problem! Should have caught it on my own, but apparently I've been staring at this code for too long.